# How to link to local file download in HTML?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using this tag:

```
<a href:"{{ arquivo.caminho }}" download>link</a>
```

With the **download** atribute to make a download link files from my local network (tiff images) but the downloaded file is a .tiff file containing the HTML code of my page.

I noticed that the link returned from my page is prefixed by address of my django:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/172.23.5.17/Imagens/etc...

My HTML code:

```
<tr>
  <td id="td_result"><p class="resultados_p">{{ resultado.nome }}</p></td>

  <td>
    <a href="{{resultado.download}}" download>
      <div class="download"></div>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Value of resultado.download:

> \\172.23.5.17\Imagens\landsat\IMAGENS_LANDSAT_8_2017\Processadas\003_068l8_oli_002065_20140803_b654_fuseo_sirgas2000_utm.tiff

(I already tried changing the bars)

Link returned by page:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/172.23.5.17/Imagens/landsat/IMAGENS_LANDSAT_8_2017/Processadas/003_068l8_oli_002065_20140803_b654_fuseo_sirgas2000_utm.tiff

Comment: Can you post the models.py file that contains the resultado model? If resultado.download is a Filefield or  an ImageField, you may need to be accessing resultado.download.url or resultado.download.file instead, but it's hard to say without the model.

Comment: I dont know the field type of resultado.download, but try: resultado.download.url